# In what way my question is actually too broad

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Now I am not trying to say [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404974/hibernation-randomly-fails-with-black-screen/404984) is not too broad to get it unheld, but I am asking what really what makes it too broad?

Really, the question gives some information a Linux expert would need, and gives the *exact* details of how the issue occurs, and eventually asks how to debug the problem.

I've done a lot of Googling, made a lot of testing, and checked a lot of logs, and I yielded nothing. I can't possibly know what causes the problem in order to try to solve it, **I am asking how to debug that.**

Is that really too broad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was one of the close voters on your question.  Let me respond to a few of the things you have said:

> I am asking how to debug that.

The word debug does not appear in your question.  In fact there is no question in your question.

> ...gives the exact details of how the issue occurs...

There is a list of symptoms that indicate a *very* flaky system, I see no way these could be described as *exact*.

> Is that really too broad?

In what way is it *not* too broad?  The broad list of symptoms, combined with no list what-so-ever of HW being used, nor any logs, journal entries or anything that could be constructively used for diagnosis means that I see no way someone could give you an answer on how to fix this.

Comment: The 'debug' word does not appear in the question, but I thought it'd be obvious that I couldn't get further. I am not exactly sure if my system is flaky honestly, it's just that some [bugs](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/777) exist with some software I have, and I put them there because they could be relevant. I also expected people to ask for details on things because I couldn't possibly know what to provide already. I think I get your point, though.

Comment: Nor any logs, journal entries or anything that could be construcitvely used for diagnosis...

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific *question* in your question. It might be interpreted as "*How do I fix my problem*" type of question, for which it is too broad as Stephen Rauch explained.

I think I voted "*unclear what you are asking*" reason but, unless I am mistaken, the close reason only lists the reason with most votes.

For the question to be re-opened, edit the question to include a (specific enough) question. Avoid asking multiple questions at once, you can always ask separate follow-up questions if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Stephen Rauch and jasonwryan already said,
“Too broad” is the close reason we use when we mean,
“There are so many things that could possibly have happened,
it’s infeasible to debug this remotely;
we’d need to read you a book on troubleshooting. 
If you can’t solve the problem with hands-on access,
you should consider taking it to a professional.”

Comment: Closing a question should let voters to actually add some piece of a clue, I think that would help a lot of people who get closed questions, the messages themselves of held questions are too broad. Either way, I edited the question. Thanks a lot.